# How to use array in erlang with text editor

Tags: arrays, erlang

I want to create an array in erlang using text editor and run it. But I have no idea how. When I browse it, it's only demonstrated in terminal.

Comment: [This blog post](http://trigonakis.com/blog/2011/03/14/introduction-to-erlang-modules-compilation/) explains how to write Erlang code in a file and compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang does not have arrays. Erlang has linked lists, which can be used like arrays but they have there own performance characteristics that make it cheap to access the first item in the list and expensive to access the last item in a large list. You can read more about linked lists here: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#lists

To create a list in a file that file will need to define a module with the same name as the file and export one or more functions. Here is what you might want:

```
-module(number_list).

-export([base_10/0]).

base_10() ->
  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].
```

Then compile the file:

```
erlc number_list.erl
```

Then use it in the `erl` shell (assuming you run `erl` in the same directory as your `number_list.beam` file):

```
erl
> number_list:base_10().
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].
```